# Informar menor código del total en pascal

Tags: pascal

tengo un ejercicio en Pascal:

Realizar un programa que lea información de 200 productos de un supermercado. De cada producto se lee código y precio (cada código es un número entre 1 y 200).

Informar en pantalla:
- Los códigos de los dos productos más baratos.
- La cantidad de productos de más de 16 pesos con código par.

Yo tengo esto resuelto, pero no sé cómo darle valor a código del menor precio:

```
program EJEJE;
var
i,codigo,precio,min1,code1,code2,min2:Integer;
begin
min1:=37000;min2:=37000;

for i:=1 to 4 do begin
    writeln('code; '); readln(codigo);
    writeln('precio; '); readln(precio);
if(precio<min1)then
begin
   min2:=min1;
   code1:=codigo;
   code2:=code1;
   min1:=precio
end

else
if(precio<min2)then
begin

     min2:=precio;
     code2:=codigo;
end;
end;
writeln('codigo mas barato: ',code1,' codigo mas barato: ',code2);
end.
```

Comment: Hola!!! que se supone que resuelve tu codigo? porque de lo que pusiste, no resuelve nada. Para guardar los dos codigos menores, tal vez deberias tener 2 variables no? Como sabes si un codigo es par? Porque lees solo 3 lineas?

Comment: Osea, primero lo quería hacer funcionar con un solo código con el precio más barato, pero ni eso pude resolver y me estanque ahí.

Comment: si el codigo de producto esta en codigo, porque a codigom le estas pasando minnim? (que para colmo es igual a i)..??? no deberias pasarle codigo?

Comment: Ya me perdí ahí, estaba probando cosas, por eso, ese IF está todo mal, eso es lo que quiero rehacer.

Comment: Ok. Y rehacelo.. Porque si no, va a parecer que hacemos el ejercicio por vos, y no vas a estar aprendiendo nada realmente ;)

Comment: Qué se ve así, pero bueno,eso es otro tema. Ahora lo tengo así el ejercicio, pero no funciona, puede ayudarme o solo vas a responder con preguntas? ...

Comment: No es que solo responda con preguntas. Puedo resolverlo y no estarias aprendiendo nada, o puedo guiarte para que entiendas el problema y puedas solucionarlo vos mismo. Si no te gusta, no te molesto mas y espera a ver si alguien te contesta algo. lo dejo a tu gusto...

Comment: Ok, pero no estás haciendo ninguna de las dos, me críticas el código,.y no me guías, solo me responda que lo haga nuevamente, cosa que hice 4 o 5 veces de cero.

Comment: OK.. Tratare de ponerte una respuesta, pero sin codigo en pascal (del cual no recuerdo mucho). Igual tu problema no es pascal. Esta mal la logica de lo que tratas de hacer. Si te tomaras 2 minutos para tratar de explicar que hace cada linea, te darias cuenta.

Comment: Revisando tu codigo, veo que lo corregiste correctamente!!! que es lo que no esta funcionando actualmente??? fijate que solamente deberias quitar el else, siempre tenes que comprobar el numero para ver si es menor...

Comment: Sugiero que utilices nombres de variables significativos. ¿Por qué `nums` y `nums2` cuando puede ser `codigo` y `precio`? Igual aplica para `min1`, etc.

Comment: Ya se, ya cambie la variables, aunque no tiene nada que ver con lo que pregunté.

Comment: editado a como lo tengo actualmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes la idea general, pero el orden de las asignaciones del primer `if` no es el correcto.

También, Como te he dicho en comentarios de la pregunta, considero que nombrar correctamente las variables es importante. La idea general la tienes en tu programa, sospecho que el hecho de tener variables como ´min1´, ´min2´, etc. puede ser la razón por la que te resulte confuso.

Acá te dejo un programa que funciona correctamente, he cambiado los nombres de las variables para mayor claridad (a mi me sirve mucho, y lo hago siempre).

```
var
  I, Codigo, Precio: Integer;
  SegundoBaratoCodigo, SegundoBaratoPrecio: Integer;
  MasBaratoCodigo, MasBaratoPrecio: Integer;
  ContadorMayor16Par: Integer;
const
  NUM_PRECIOS = 4;
begin
  SegundoBaratoPrecio := MaxInt;
  MasBaratoPrecio := MaxInt;
  SegundoBaratoCodigo := 0;
  MasBaratoCodigo := 0;
  ContadorMayor16Par := 0;
  for I := 1 to NUM_PRECIOS do
  begin
    writeln('Codigo: '); readln(Codigo);
    writeln('Precio: '); readln(Precio);
    if Precio < MasBaratoPrecio then
    begin
      //Primero pasamos el más barato al SegundoBarato
      SegundoBaratoPrecio := MasBaratoPrecio;
      SegundoBaratoCodigo := MasBaratoCodigo;
      //Ahora asignamos el más barato
      MasBaratoPrecio := Precio;
      MasBaratoCodigo := Codigo;
    end
    else if Precio < SegundoBaratoPrecio then
    begin
      //Simplemente asignamos el SegundoBarato
      SegundoBaratoPrecio := Precio;
      SegundoBaratoCodigo := Codigo;
    end;
    if (Precio > 16) and (not Odd(Codigo)) then
      Inc(ContadorMayor16Par);
  end;
  Writeln;
  Writeln('2 Articulos mas baratos');
  Writeln('Codigo: ', MasBaratoCodigo, ' Precio: ', MasBaratoPrecio);
  Writeln('Codigo: ', SegundoBaratoCodigo, ' Precio: ', SegundoBaratoPrecio);
  Writeln;
  Writeln('Contador de articulos con precio mayor a 16 y codigo par: ', ContadorMayor16Par);
  readln;
end.
```

En el programa, además del cambio de nombre de variables, he hecho uso de constantes, estándar como `MaxInt` o declaradas en el código, como `NUM_PRECIOS`, que también mejoran la legibilidad del código.